# Solving and plotting ODE with dependent parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, ode, scientific-computing

I'm working on a bit of code where I have the following system of equations [here](http://mathb.in/24788?key=6a7c0c925c2a90b965b53e74063409fbb9de30fe). The issue being that I'd very much like to solve for multiple values of k as well as have a phase plane/quiver plot for each value of k. Can someone please help me? This is what I have so far for the solver:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def model(X, t):
    x = X[0]
    y = X[1]
    dxdt = k*x - y
    dydt = x + y
    return [dxdt, dydt]
#Initial state 
X0 = [1,1]

#Time
t = np.linspace(0,10)

X = odeint(model, X0, t)
```

And this is what I have so far for plotting:

```
x = X[:,0]
y = X[:,1]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Please note, I'm not trying to simply solve the system! I'm trying to solve it with multiple values changing (k) and plotting the resulting equations.

Comment: Iterate over k and add the plot to the existing window.

Comment: I  can appreciate that's what I should do, but I'm having a really hard time getting it to work. I understand that I need to add it to my definition
`def model(X,t,k) `, but I keep getting an error for k = (1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over k, and pass the value as an additional parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def model(X, t, k):
    x = X[0]
    y = X[1]
    dxdt = k*x - y
    dydt = x + y
    return [dxdt, dydt]
#Initial state 
X0 = [1,1]

#Time
t = np.linspace(0,10)
Ks = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)

for kix in Ks:
    X = odeint(model, X0, t, args=(kix,))
    x = X[:,0]
    y = X[:,1]
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful! I can try the quiver plot myself. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

With some more computational effort you can use

```
xvalues, yvalues = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-2, 2, 0.02), np.arange(-2, 2, 0.02))
Ks = np.linspace(-1, 1, 12)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4,wspace=0.4)
for j,kix in enumerate(Ks):
    xdot, ydot = model([xvalues,yvalues],0 , kix)
    plt.subplot(3,4,j+1)
    plt.streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot, density=0.5)
    plt.title("k=%.2f"%kix)

plt.show()
```

to get

[image]